# Rails 4 won't start server or db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

New to rails 4 here, i've had a look through other questions but can't seem to find the answer, feel free to point me in the right direction!

Here is my error code for attempting to run the rails server:

```
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `rescue in execute_if_updated': Rails::Application::RoutesReloader#execute_if_updated delegated to updater.execute_if_updated, but updater is nil: #<Rails::Application::RoutesReloader:0x007fe70babade8 @paths=["/Users/mac/autostudy/config/routes.rb"], @route_sets=[#<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007fe70b96aa60>]> (RuntimeError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/mac/autostudy/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /Users/mac/autostudy/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/mac/autostudy/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/mac/autostudy/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Here is my error code attempting to run a rake db:migrate:

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
Rails::Application::RoutesReloader#execute_if_updated delegated to updater.execute_if_updated, but updater is nil: #<Rails::Application::RoutesReloader:0x007f9f29225838 @paths=["/Users/mac/autostudy/config/routes.rb"], @route_sets=[#<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007f9f2b890ab8>]>
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `rescue in execute_if_updated'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/mac/autostudy/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:249:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

I apologise if the question is already answered or obvious - i honestly couldn't find it.

Thanks in advance!

config/routes.rb file:

```
  Autostudy::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts

  get "admin" => "admin#index" 
  resources :resources

  resources :contents

  resources :courses

  resources :user_profiles


  authenticated :user do
    root "home#index"
  end
  root "home#index"
  resources :users, :only => [:index, :show, :edit, :update ]
  get '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#create'
  get '/signin' => 'sessions#new', :as => :signin
  get '/signout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :signout
  get '/auth/failure' => 'sessions#failure'
end
```

Comment: Post your config/routers.rb file

Comment: Are you using older version of devise than 3? If so, you have to upgrade.

Comment: Checked it out thanks; Devise is already up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the tips. Turns out it was this part in my routes file it didn't like:

```
  authenticated :user do
    root "home#index"
  end
  root "home#index"
```

So i changed it back to just:

```
    root "home#index"
```

And everything works fine. Thanks, i'll just do authenticated login pages a different way.